# Conditionally taking elements from a Stream

Tags: stream, conditional-statements, elixir, take

I've implemented the following function:

```erlang
  def gaussian(center, height, width) do
    Stream.iterate(1, &(&1 + 1))
    |> Stream.map(fn (x) -> x - center end)
    |> Stream.map(fn (x) -> :math.pow(x, 2) end)
    |> Stream.map(fn (x) -> -x / (2 * :math.pow(width, 2))  end)
    |> Stream.map(fn (x) -> height * :math.exp(x) end)
    |> Stream.map(&Kernel.round/1)
    |> Stream.take_while(&(&1 > 0))
    |> Enum.to_list                                                            
  end
```

With the given args, an empty list is returned:

```erlang
iex> gaussian(10, 10, 3)
[]
```

Removing the `Stream.take_while/2`

```erlang
  def gaussian(center, height, width) do
    Stream.iterate(1, &(&1 + 1))
    |> Stream.map(fn (x) -> x - center end)
    |> Stream.map(fn (x) -> :math.pow(x, 2) end)
    |> Stream.map(fn (x) -> -x / (2 * :math.pow(width, 2))  end)
    |> Stream.map(fn (x) -> height * :math.exp(x) end)
    |> Stream.map(&Kernel.round/1)
    #|> Stream.take_while(&(&1 > 0))                                                   
    #|> Enum.to_list                                                                   
    |> Enum.take(20)
  end
```

gives this however:

```
iex> gaussian(10, 10, 3)
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 9, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Is there something wrong with my `Stream.take_while/2` call, or am I missing something altogether here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Stream.take_while/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#take_while/2) stops evaluation on the first occurrence of the the function evaluating to `false`.

In your case, your function in:

```
|> Stream.take_while(&(&1 > 0))
```

with specified arguments like

```
gaussian(10, 10, 3)
```

in first iteration receives `0` thus it doesn't iterate further as your expression `&1 > 0` evaluates to `false`.

You can check that yourself if you expand your code to something like:

```
|> Stream.take_while(fn (x) -> IO.inspect(x); x > 0 end)
```

Maybe its [`Stream.filter/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2) you wanted to use?

Hope that helps you resolving your problem!

Comment: Thanks, `IO.inspect/1` really helps - `Stream.filter/2` seems to try and operate on the infinite stream, so doesn't complete.

Comment: @category What would be the completion condition then? Is there one? Or maybe you want to take only first `20` elements like in your other example? Then you need to replace `|> Enum.to_list` with `|> Enum.take(20)`. This is nature of streams they can evaluate infinite if no termination condition is specified.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the completion condition - using that with `Stream.with_index/2`, I managed to define a conditional that inspects the number of deviations after the centre.